# I want to replace characters(*, ', ?, :, /,\,all) in a random String( of any size length & any type of characters)

Tags: regex, replace

I have generated a random string of varaible size length which include lower, upper, numbers & punctuation.

I am writing an API which takes input for any of these characters `(*, ', ?, :, /,\)` & generate the random string with or without the given character

Example:

```
randomStringWithSpecialChar(boolean specChar, String... specialChars){

String randomString = "GHHG#^%^57687987*'?:/\fgdg"

if(!specChar){ 

   # I should replace (*, ', ?, :, /,\) with x, so that I can pass it as my testdata

   String finalString = "GHHG#^%^57687987xxxxxxfgdg"

}

return finalString

}
```

Comment: Are you programming in java? (if not what language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Java. You can use [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
str.replaceAll("[*'?:/\\\\]", "x")
```

This takes a matches any of the characters in the set and replaces it with `x`. Note the `\\\\` is escaping the slash.

Comment: The random string may or may not contain these special characters ... Will str.replaceAll handle that scenario ??

Comment: I guess we have something called X* in regex ... that should handle, but how should I use X* (X, zero or more times) in the above regex

Comment: @VarunMukka If the character don't appear in the string nothing will be replaced.